# Is the Evening Prophet a separate newspaper or part of the Daily Prophet?

Tags: harry-potter

An answer to my last question said:

> **"There was also a mention of [an] Evening Prophet in Half-Blood Prince but
>   it isn't clear if it's a real newspaper or just [the] Daily Prophet's
>   edition."**

Is it known which one is correct?

Answer (score 19):

Per the latest release of information from [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-daily-prophet):

> *"There is only one wizarding newspaper in Britain, discounting such small circulation publications such as The Quibbler. The Daily
>   Prophet, whose headquarters are in Diagon Alley, is delivered by owl
>   on a daily basis to nearly every wizarding household in Britain.
>   Payment is effected by placing coins in the pouch tied to the
>   paper-owl's leg.*
>
> *Occasionally (when something particularly interesting or exciting happens, such as the illegal flight of a Ford Anglia the length of
>   Britain) an **Evening Prophet** edition will be rushed out."*

In the films, the masthead for the Evening Prophet is also basically identical to that of the Daily Prophet.

[image]

Notably, the pottermore website also mentions a "Sunday Prophet" and includes a small photograph on the same page. Since the paper is generally known as 'The Prophet' to the various characters, it's highly likely that any newspaper calling itself "The *...something...* Prophet" would be connected.

[image]

Comment: Um... isn't that the same Pottermore quote I provided in my answer?

Comment: @dvk - Yes, but not everyone has a pottermore account.

Comment: Yes, that's why I included the screenshot :)

Comment: Also, Sunday Prophet isn't really clear as far as being a Daily's edition. I posted it as a question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56473/is-there-a-solid-canon-evidence-that-sunday-prophet-is-an-edition-part-of-daily

Comment: @dvk - AFAIK : The Sunday Prophet picture is from the Daily Prophet article on Pottermore. PLease feel free to correct me as my login has just timed out...

Comment: @DVK - Some people like to read more than just the quote, they want to read the context and surround as well :-)

Answer (score 9):

According to Pottermore's "New Content from JKRowling"  ([Book4/Chapter18/Moment2 - Daily Prophet](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-daily-prophet)), it's the latter:

[image]

Comment: There's also a "Sunday Prophet", mentioned in OotP Chapter 38, but I haven't been able to find a definitive proof of it also being an edition of Daily one. The only good evidence is that [this Quidditch article](http://www.pottermore.com/en/daily-prophet/qwc2014/2014-04-13/nor-v-civ) from Pottermore has a Sunday date.

Comment: It's referenced on the pottermore website (see screenshot here; http://i.stack.imgur.com/a4rLw.png