# Is there a solid canon evidence that Sunday Prophet is an edition part of Daily Prophet?

Tags: harry-potter

Came up with something that was on [Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Sunday_Prophet) but not very well sourced while researching [my last answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56468/is-evening-prophet-a-separate-newspaper-or-part-of-daily-prophet).

In *Order of Phoenix, Ch. 38, The Second War Begins*, they read "Sunday Prophet".

> Harry was sitting on the end of Ron's bed and they were both listening to Hermione read the front page of the **Sunday Prophet**.

Wikia says that it's an *edition* of Daily Prophet, like [Evening Prophet](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56468/is-evening-prophet-a-separate-newspaper-or-part-of-daily-prophet) is.

But their only proof - very weak one IMHO - is that there is a **Daily** Prophet example published on Sunday - specifically, [4/13/2014 - Ginny Weasley Quidditch report "Norway vs Ivory Coast"](http://www.pottermore.com/en/daily-prophet/qwc2014/2014-04-13/nor-v-civ). However, that link doesn't actually say "Sunday Prophet" anywhere on it!

**Is there an actual solid canon proof that Sunday Prophet is an edition of The Daily Prophet** aside from this "not called Sunday Prophet" example and a mere fact that they are both called "Prophet" (which is evidence, but there's 1000s of Muggle newspapers called "News" or "Post" so it's not exactly proof).

Notably, Pottermore's Daily Prophet article mentions Evening Prophet but **NOT** Sunday.

Comment: That's how newspaper naming works in the UK.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### The Sunday Prophet is the "Sunday Edition" of the Daily Prophet.

The Daily Prophet office on the old Pottermore website contained various editions of the Daily Prophet that were available for viewing.

As you can see from the screenshot below, the paper on the right is the "Daily Prophet" whereas the paper on the left is clearly marked as the "**Sunday Prophet**".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, the Sunday Prophet is part of the Daily Prophet

If we look at some passages discussing this issue of the paper, it seems pretty clear that they are referencing back to what the Daily Prophet has been saying all year. This makes sense if they are the same paper, but not if they are two different papers:

> “He’s ‘the Boy Who Lived’ again now, though, isn’t  he?” said Ron
>   darkly. “Not such a show-off maniac 
>   anymore, eh?”

> “Yes, they’re very complimentary about you now,  Harry,” said
>   Hermione, now scanning down the  article. “ ‘A lone voice of truth ...
>   perceived as  unbalanced, yet never wavered in his story . . . forced
>   to  bear ridicule and slander ...’ Hmmm,” said Hermione,  frowning, “I
>   notice they don’t mention the fact that it  was them doing all the
>   ridiculing and slandering,  though...”

> “ ‘You-Know- Who’s Last Attempt to Take Over, pages  two to four, What
>   the Ministry Should Have Told Us,  page five, Why Nobody Listened to
>   Albus Dumbledore,  pages six to eight, Exclusive Interview with Harry 
>   Potter, page nine ...’ Well,” said Hermione, folding up  the newspaper
>   and throwing it aside, “it’s certainly  given them lots to write
>   about. And that interview  with Harry isn’t exclusive, it’s the one
>   that was in The  Quibbler months ago...”

Additionally, when Harry goes to visit Hagrid that same day, we have the following:

> The hot sun hit him with a blast as he walked across  the lawns toward
>   Hagrid’s cabin. Students lying  around on the grass sunbathing,
>   talking, reading the  Sunday Prophet, and eating sweets looked up at
>   him  as he passed. Some called out to him, or else waved,  clearly
>   eager to show that they, like the Prophet, had  decided he was
>   something of a hero.

In this passage the Sunday Prophet is referred to as just "the Prophet" which is what the Daily Prophet is referred to as throughout the books. That would make sense if they are the same newspaper. If they are two different newspapers, they likely would not be flippantly referred to in the same way.